# PHP PDO postgresql -- I just want the hash names, not numerated?

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

Real basic here:

```
$db = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=gangsterbase;host=localhost", "sexyadmin", "ohhhhhyeahhhhh" );
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM datFineLookinTable WHERE name LIKE :name ;");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

But my return is of course:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Something] => foo
            [0] => foo
            [somethingElse] => herp
            [1] => herp
            [AnotherSomethingElse] => derp
            [2] => derp
        )
)
```

But I just want

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Something] => foo
            [somethingElse] => herp
            [AnotherSomethingElse] => derp
        )
)
```

Without post-processing to remove array elements, how do I get PDO to return like this?

Comment: nice database password, thought ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

It's not in the `fetchAll` documentation, but it is in the `fetch` documentation.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php